# Dotnet test command worked locally but failed in GitLab-Runner

Tags: .net, gitlab, pipeline, cicd

I am running pipeline in GitLab. My project is composed of a WPF Application and a MSTest project which uses FlaUI.
**My Problem** is that the pipeline was stucked in ｀dotnet test --no-restore` in *test* stage.

Here is my **pipeline** script:

```
variables:
  OBJECTS_DIRECTORY: obj
  NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY:". nuget"
  SOURCE_CODE_PATH:GetPassword/

before_script:
  -dotnetrestore--packages$NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY--source" https://mirrors.abc.com/nuget/index.json ”

build:
  stage:build
  script:
    - 'dotnet build --no-restore'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      -“$SOURCE_CODE_PATH/ bin/*/”

tests:
  stage:test
  dependencies:
    -build
  script:
    - 'dotnet test --no-restore'
```

**Pipeline Output:**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.1.0
Using Shell executor...
...
$ dotnet restore --packages $NUGET_PACKAGES＿DIRECTORY -- source "hhtps://mirrors.abc.com/nuget/index.json"
...
$ dotnet test --no-restore
TestProject1 -< D:\Softwares\GItLab-Runner\builds\...\TestProject1.dll
Test run for D:\Softwares\GitLab-Runner\builds\...\TestProject1.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.4.0(x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test file matches the specified pattern.
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds
```

What's wrong with the pipeline or my runner?

**I have checked:**
The test project can be run in local powershell.
My GitLab-Runner is installed in my local. It's executor is **shell**.
The application was launched after pipeline test started. I attached Vistual Studio 2022 on the process and found that the application was stucked in `GetMessage()` of `System.Windows.Application.Run()`.